# OptionsPattern[] taken as a Replacement Rule

Tags: options

I was trying to write my own plot function taking as unit size cm instead of points. I've tried

```
Options[MyPlot] = Options[Plot];
SetOptions[MyPlot, ImageSize -> {8.22, 5.03}];
MyPlot[fun_, int_, opts_: OptionsPattern[]] := {fun, int, 
  ImageSize -> OptionValue[MyPlot, opts, ImageSize]*72/2.54};
Plot @@ MyPlot[Sin[2 \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 10]
```

and with

```
Options[MyGraphics] = Options[Graphics];
SetOptions[MyGraphics, ImageSize -> {8.22, 5.03}];
MyGraphics[prims_, opts_: OptionsPattern[]] := {prims, 
  ImageSize -> OptionValue[MyGraphics, opts, ImageSize]*72/2.54};
Graphics@@MyGraphics[Rectangle[]]
```

the error: OptionValue::rep: "OptionsPattern[] is not a valid replacement rule." came out.

Where am I wrong? It seems I am a  bit confusing on the way to use OptionsPattern[] and using `_` or `__` in the function arguments before the opts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You must use `opts : OptionsPattern[]` and not `opts_ : OptionsPattern[]`.

The `:` character has a double role: it can indicate a pattern name or an optional argument.  If the left-hand-side is a symbol then it indicates a pattern name, otherwise it indicates an optional argument.

Examples:

`a_` is a [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) named `a`.

`a : _` is a blank named `a` using `:` syntax.

`a_ : x` is a blank named `a` as optional argument with default value `x`.

`_ : x` is an unnamed optional blank with default value `x` (I'm not sure if this has any use at all).

`a : _ : x` is a blank named `a` as optional argument with default value `x`.

Comment: The `x: _ : x` pattern isn't unnamed: it's a `Blank` pattern with name `x` and default value `x`. Try: `f[x : _ : x] := x`, then `f[]` returns `x` and `f[1]` returns `1`. The case `x: a : _ : x` is also misinterpreted (but more complicated).

Comment: The pattern `x : a : _ : x` means "the pattern `a` named `x` with default value `_ : x`": try `Clear[f, a, x]; f[x : a : _ : x] := x`, then `f[]` returns the default value `_ : x`, `f[a]` returns `a` and `f[1]` returns unevaluated because `1` doesn't match the pattern `a`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I wrote it in a confusing way, so you thought that some colons that were just punctuation in the text were actually code.  I rewrote it to avoid confusion: I put the code at the beginning of each line.

Comment: (+1) Now it is clear. I'll keep my comments since despite they don't correspond to the answer anymore they still can have some educational value.